# C++ Recursion Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int findSumofOdds(int n);

int main()
{

  int n = 88;
  int x;

  x = findSumofOdds(n);
  cout << x << endl;


  return 0;
}

int findSumofOdds(int n)
{
  if (n != 1)
  {
    if( n % 2 == 0)
      n = (n - 1);

    return(findSumofOdds(n-1) + 1);
  }
  else
    return 1;
}
```

Why isn't this recursion working? It tries to run and then crashes. Please let me know. My teacher said that it would work but doesn't.

Comment: You know that there's a closed-form formula for that, don't you? 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + 2n-1 = n*n.

Answer (score 5):

When `n` is even, you are decrementing `n` by two. If it skips over `n == 1`, it will recurse until it causes a stack overflow. Since `n` starts out at 88, that's what's happening.

```
int findSumofOdds(int n)
{
    if (n != 1)
    {
        if( n % 2 == 0)
            n = (n - 1); // <== first decrement

        return(findSumofOdds(n-1) + 1); // <== second decrement
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Also, you seem to be *counting* the number of odd numbers, not adding them. My guess is that you actually want something like:

```
int findSumofOdds(int n)
{
    if (n != 1)
    {
        if( n % 2 == 0)
            return(findSumofOdds(n - 1));

        return(findSumofOdds(n-1) + n); // or + 1 to just count
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

If you want to practice recursion, that's fine. But there's a much simpler way to write a function to sum the odd numbers up to and including `n`:

```
int fundSumofOdds(int n) {
    n = (n + 1) / 2;
    return n * n;
}
```

This is because there's a general formula:

> 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + 2n-1 = n<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it

```
if (n > 1)
```

Consider `n = 2` here

```
 if (n != 1)
 {
   if( n % 2 == 0)  // Yes
      n = (n - 1);  // n = 1

   return(findSumofOdds(n-1) + 1);  // n = 0  <-- will not stop.
```

---

and  change this too. right now it is just counting the number of odd numbers. You need to sum them.

```
   return(n + findSumofOdds(n - 1));
}
else
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print `n` in `findSumofOdds` you can see what is happening -- `n` becomes negative and you get infinite recursion. If your program doesn't crash earlier, you can get integer overflow (when `n` goes below the minimum value for `int`) which yields undefined behavior.
To correct this you can do this:

```
int findSumofOdds(int n)
{
    if(n < 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return findSumofOdds(n - 1) + 1;
    }
    return findSumofOdds(n - 2) + 1;
}
```

You can subtract 2 from `n` in the last statement, because you only need odd numbers and you know that `n` can't be even at that point (because of `if(n % 2 == 0)`).

Also, do you need to find the sum of all odd numbers smaller than `n` (e.g. `4` (`== 1 + 3`) for `n=5`) or do you just need to count them (which is what you are doing now)?
If you want to sum the numbers, you have do add `n` instead of `1` when returning.